# C++ Generic way to provide `operator<<` for middleware generated types

Tags: c++, templates, middleware

We use a middleware that generates types for us for various programming languages, including C++. For structures generated for C++ I want to inject code that can be used for various data conversion, for example output to `std::ostream`. Let's say we have following structure generated:

```
struct Foo {
    int a;
    double d;
};
```

Let's say I change middleware compiler to produce following template function:

```
template<typename Visitor>
void visit( Visitor &v, const Foo &data )
{
    v.visit( "a", data.a );
    v.visit( "d", data.d );
}
```

now I can use this code for various ways and it should not affect anything if not used, for example make `std::ostream::operator<<`:

```
struct OstreamVisitor {
    OstreamVisitor( std::ostream &os ) : m_os( os ) {}

    void visit( const char *name, int i ) { m_os << name << "=" << i << std::endl; }
    void visit( const char *name, double d ) { m_os << name << "=" << d << std::endl; }

    std::ostream &m_os;
};

std::ostream &operator<<( std::ostream &out, const Foo &data )
{
    OstreamVisitor v( out );
    visit( v, data );
    return out;
}
```

it works [live example](https://ideone.com/GiSpso) but problem is I do not want to write `std::ostream &operator<<` for every structure manually so naive solution would be to write:

```
template<typename T>
std::ostream &operator<<( std::ostream &os, const T &t );
```

and use visitor, but that would interfere with other types, that not generated. So is there way to make such generic function that limited only for structures, that generated? I would like not to inject anything to generated structures if possible but having template class instead of template function is fine.

Note: I cannot restrict generated structs to belong to particular namespace unfortunately. What I am thinking is something like:

```
// system header
template<typename T>
struct visitable_tag;

// generated header
namespace FooNamespace {
struct Foo { ... };

template<>
struct visitable_tag<Foo> {};
}

 // or maybe have tag in special namespace
 namespace visitable_tag_namespace {
 template<>
 struct visitable_tag<FooNamespace::Foo> {};
 }
```

and then make template output function only instantiate when such specialization exits. Of course this is just idea of possible tagging and I open to other ways, but would prefer to have original structures untouched.

Comment: Define your `operator<<` template in the same namespace as that of the types generated by your middleware compiler.

Comment: @Praetorian That would make a nice answer

Comment: Another option is an empty interface/base class, used only for "tagging".  The compiler will apply empty base optimization so the extra base class has no runtime effect.  And then you can use SFINAE to activate `operator<<` only for classes derived from the tag type.

Comment: @Praetorian unfortunately those types are generated in different namespaces

Comment: @PasserBy I was pretty much certain a restriction like the comment above would pop up for that answer :) Slava, you claim you can modify the compiler, so maybe you can get it to generate these types in one, or just a handful of namespaces.

Comment: @Praetorian I am trying to use for already defined types that already use multiple namespaces intentionally and there is code that depends on tha, so I cannot change it.

Comment: @BenVoigt yes tagging would be a perfect solution but I am not sure how to implement it properly in this case

Comment: One way of achieving it would be to derive your structs from something like Visitable in CRTP fashion, call derived visit in Visitable visit and make your `ostream<< ` operator accept reference to Visitable. It doesn't agree with non-changing of the structs, though.

Comment: Since you have a generator to create these types. Can't you use this generator to write `operator<<` for each of your structs ? It's more verbose but you don't have to write this code.

Comment: @GuillaumeGris the problem is `operator<<` is only one case, I would need more, for example convert such struct to json etc, I do not want to change generator for every conversion I add later

Comment: I had a similar situation generating automated classes from an xsd (xml schema document). We ultimately decided to make our middleware compiler generate the `operator <<` for all types. It's equally performant, and the code bloat relatively wasn't too bad in our case. Biggest advantage though I'd say was code readability, admittedly a very personal opinion.

Comment: @ParakramMajumdar unfortunately generating operator<< is not flexible, I need multiple different conversion generated and want it to be extendable for even more later

Answer (score 0):

You could use combination of Macro's and SFINAE. Or take a look at Boost Hana:

http://boostorg.github.io/hana/index.html#tutorial-introspection-adapting

You can keep the macro stuff low level and buil your higher level code upon that

Comment: Yea macro would work but I'd like to avoid it, but if it is not possible will probably use it

Answer (score 0):

another approach could be using clang lib to autogenerate the output code from your structs. in that case your main code would stay clean. i'm not expert on this, but it may be worth a try

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I implemented:

```
// header before generated types
namespace visitor_details {
template<typename T>
struct visitor_caller : std::false_type {};
}

// generated header
// types in various namespace
namespace foobar {

struct Foo { // this struct has generated helper
    int a = 1;
    double d = 2;
};

struct NotFoo { // this one does not, for testing
    int c;
};

}
// injected code generation
namespace visitor_details {
template<>
struct visitor_caller<foobar::Foo> : std::true_type {
    template<typename Visitor, typename T>
    static void visit( Visitor &v, T &&f )
    {
        v.visit( "a", f.a );
        v.visit( "d", f.d );
    }
};
}

// usage
struct OstreamVisitor {
    OstreamVisitor( std::ostream &os ) : m_os( os ) {}

    void visit( const char *name, int i ) { m_os << name << "=" << i << std::endl; }
    void visit( const char *name, double d ) { m_os << name << "=" << d << std::endl; }

    std::ostream &m_os;
};

template<typename T, typename EN = typename std::enable_if<visitor_details::visitor_caller<T>::value>::type >
std::ostream &operator<<( std::ostream &out, const T &data )
{
    OstreamVisitor v( out );
    visitor_details::visitor_caller<T>::visit( v, data );
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    foobar::Foo f;
    std::cout << f;
    foobar::NotFoo n;
    //std::cout << n;
}
```

now if I uncomment last line in `main` error says:

> error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}’ and ‘foobar::NotFoo’)

so looks like this is what I need

[live example](https://ideone.com/yI5scT)